# C# add items in combobox manually

Tags: c#, combobox

I have a problem in manipulating comboBoxes. There are three comboboxes. If I change the selected index on the 1st combobox then values in the 2nd and 3rd should be updated. An
IndexOutOfRange exception occurs. I know, in start, I have 3 data items... when I change the index of the 1st then the 2nd must have 8 to 9 values. Here occur exception
2nd combobox have 3 values. 
now if 1st is changed then here occur exception

```
private void comboBox3_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
        if (comboBox3.SelectedIndex == 1)
        {                         
            comboBox1.Items[0]="Kilometer";
            comboBox1.Items[1]="Meter";
            comboBox1.Items[2]="Centimeter";
            comboBox1.Items[3]="Millimeter";
            comboBox1.Items[4]="Mile";
            comboBox1.Items[5]="Yard";
            comboBox1.Items[6]="Foot";
            comboBox1.Items[7]="Inch";
            comboBox1.Items[8] = "Nautical Mile";            

            comboBox2.Items[0] = "Meter";
            comboBox2.Items[1] = "Centimeter";
            comboBox2.Items[2] = "Millimeter";
            comboBox2.Items[3] = "Mile";
            comboBox2.Items[4] = "Yard";
            comboBox2.Items[5] = "Foot";
            comboBox2.Items[6] = "Inch";
            comboBox2.Items[7] = "Nautical Mile";
            comboBox2.Items[8] = "Kilometer";
        }
        else if (comboBox3.SelectedIndex == 2) 
        {
            comboBox1.Items[0] = "Metric ton";
            comboBox1.Items[1] = "Kilogram";
            comboBox1.Items[2] = "Gram";
            comboBox1.Items[3] = "Milligram";
            comboBox1.Items[4] = "Mcg";
            comboBox1.Items[5] = "Long ton";
            comboBox1.Items[6] = "Short ton";
            comboBox1.Items[7] = "Stone";
            comboBox1.Items[8] = "Pound";
            comboBox1.Items[9] = "Ounce";            
        }
}
```

Comment: Please take some time to format your question (and to make clear what you need) before posting. We'll feel it deserves our time to answer it.

Comment: visit the link i shared , actually i wanna add new items in 2nd and 3rd combobox by selecting values from 1st

Comment: Which framework are you using? C# is just the language.

Comment: \http://www.google.com/search?q=feet+to+meter+converter&sourceid=ie7&rls=com.microsoft:en-US&ie=utf8&oe=utf8

Comment: I mean which GUI framework. ComboBox is not standard C#, it is a GUI component type. Plus, your link does not show any code. Please add code directly in the question, not as an external link which may go away.

Comment: wait i am trying to explain you

Comment: Add() combobox items, when it's empty Items[0] will throw IndexOutOfRangeException. Can I suggest to try first with a very basic single control WinForms application? Better following a tutorial...

Comment: there are 3 item in 1st combobox, but i want new 8 in 2nd when i select value form 1st

Comment: You should also be clearing the combobox items instead of overwriting the items.

Comment: @AndrewGrinder how to clear comboBox for values

Comment: @A.RShaib see my answer posted below

Answer (score 1):

When you can it's often better practice to avoid accessing and changing objects by their index in a collection, e.g. when you can use foreach, use that rather than a for with the index.

For instance, in this case you can create a List from an array (defined in the code of the objects), and set the .Items collection to this.  This avoids the usage of any numbers.  You can also store references to the comboBox1 items and use .SelectedItem rather than .SelectedIndex, for instance if there was ever any chance that more items would be added to that combo box.

Comment: `MyObject myObject = new MyObject();` --> `cb.Items.Add(myObject);` `if(cb.SelectedItem != null)` --> `MyObject myObject = (MyObject)cb.SelectedItem;` In "MyObject" have `public String Text {get;set;}` and `public int SomeID {get;set;}`

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean ArgumentOutOfRangeException. It is likely because you are directly assigning to non-existent index locations. You need to use Add() or AddRange() to add the items.

```
comboBox1.Items.Add("Metric ton");
//...
comboBox1.Items.Add("Ounce");
```

Winforms ComboBox.Items is of type ObjectCollection. Use of index[0] notation is valid for values that already exist, but not for adding.

The same exception can also be caused by setting ComboBox.SelectedIndex to a value that is out of range. Remember the collection index is zero-based, which means if you have 3 items, they use indexes [0..2]

You can also clear the items with Items.Clear() or remove specific Items with Items.Remove("something") or Items.RemoveAt(i)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.objectcollection.add(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: combo1Box.Items.Add("my item"); item added but values are added where i want remove values and than add new

Comment: Use Items.RemoveAt(index) or Items.Remove("my item")

Comment: See the link I posted which gives you all of the methods for the Items property.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.objectcollection(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
private void comboBox3_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    if (comboBox3.SelectedIndex == 1)
    {    
        comboBox1.Items.Clear();       
        comboBox1.Items.Add("Kilometer");
        // and so on
        comboBox2.Items.Clear();
        comboBox2.Items.Add("Meter");
        // and so on
    }
    else if(comboBox3.SelectedIndex == 2)
    {
        comboBox1.Items.Clear();       
        comboBox1.Items.Add("Metric ton");
        // and so on
    }
}
```

Alternatively

```
private String[] comboBoxOneItemsArraySetOne = { "SetOneItem1", "SetOneItems2" };
private String[] comboBoxOneItemsArraySetTwo = { "SetTwoItem1", "SetTwoItems2" };
private String[] comboBoxTwoItemsArray = { "Item1", "Items2" };

private void comboBox3_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    if (comboBox3.SelectedIndex == 1)
    {    
        comboBox1.Items.Clear();

        foreach(String s in comboBoxOneItemsArraySetOne)
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Add(s);
        }

        comboBox2.Items.Clear();

        foreach(String s in comboBoxTwoItemsArray)
        {
            comboBox2.Items.Add(s);
        }
    }
    else if(comboBox3.SelectedIndex == 2)
    {
        comboBox1.Items.Clear(); 

        foreach(String s in comboBoxOneItemsArraySetTwo)
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Add(s);
        }
    }
}
```